# How to fetch data from database in jquery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a js file that is using an image array . in that array there is name of images that are to be used on client side page. I want that image name from database. I am using asp.net technology. Please help me out.

Comment: So you'll need to set up a handler that returns you a JSON array of data that you've read from the database then call it with `$.ajax()`. Which specific bit do you need help with?

Comment: have a look at this question, its not exaclty what you expect but will give you a idea what need to be done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002031/connecting-jquery-with-the-sql-server-database

Answer (score 0):

Please use JQuery for the same.
Use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ link for reference.

Create Handler in asp.net I mean create .ashx file.
Put the server side code as you like and get the image name from database.

Call Handler file using Jquery $ajax api and get the result as you required.

Please let me know if you have any problem.

Thanks